# Why does a call to vector::back() remove the data at the back of my vector?

Tags: c++, vector, assign

I want to assign the value at the back of my vector to another element:

```
iter->second.connection = myConnection->newConnections.back();
```

However, this call effectively empties out the contents at `.back()` -- why?

**Data before call:**

```
fd                  int                 6   
sin_size            socklen_t           16  
theirAddress        sockaddr_storage    {...}   
ipstr               char [46]           0x60c498
```

**After call:**

```
fd                  int                 null    
sin_size            socklen_t           null    
theirAddress        sockaddr_storage    {...}   
ipstr               char [46]           0x88
```

For reference, the types I'm trying to assign are the struct:

```
struct NodeConnection
{
    int fd;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_storage theirAddress; 
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int port;
};
```

And here is the declaration of newConnections:

```
vector<NodeConnection> newConnections;
```

Comment: An `int` cannot have the value "null."  The `back()` function is not modifying the element; something else is.  Your debugger can tell you exactly what is modifying the data.  Set a data breakpoint or step through each of the functions in the span of code during which the object is modified.

Comment: Sorry, I just added that to represent that it was blank - Eclipse shows just <blank space> as the value.

Comment: You have to show your actual code.

Comment: [.back() does not have this effect](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09b609fe229ef114) please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) which reproduces the error.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. The before and after data that I posted are from me sitting on the line (before) --> hitting F6 to step over --> and then getting the same member values again (after). There are no calls between.

Comment: Still, there is no error in the above statements, we need more info as the error is likely somewhere else. Does `NodeConnection` have any constructors or assignment operators or is it just the struct you showed us?